# In Jenkins TestNG Results, Fail test case link, opens with an error message

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

**TestNG: version 6.10,**Java:8,Test Cases Count:Total Tests: 743, Failed Tests: 19**

Scenario:
1. API Test cases are written in Java + Rest assured + TestNG + Maven framework. 
2. Running test cases with jenkin.
3.In Post-build action, have added, publish testng report.

Expecting Result: In testng failed test cases list, when I click on any fail test cases, it should navigate to failure exception page and show me the failure reason.

*Note: I am not able to log this bug in jenkin site as I am not having the expected permission.*

Actual Output: A problem occurred while processing the request.

Stack trace

> org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.89.4.jar!/lib/layout/layout.jelly:267:25:  org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.89.4.jar!/lib/layout/main-panel.jelly:36:21:  org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: Cannot get property 'escapeTestDescp' on null object
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:726)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:281)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:276)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.Namespace$ProxyImpl.invoke(Namespace.java:92)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.layout(Unknown Source)
>       at lib.LayoutTagLib$layout$0.call(Unknown Source)
>       at hudson.plugins.testng.results.MethodResult.index.run(index.groovy:8)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:74)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:62)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:112)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet.handleIndexRequest(JellyFacet.java:140)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.IndexViewDispatcher.dispatch(IndexViewDispatcher.java:30)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
>       at com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugin.assetbundler.filters.LessCSS.doFilter(LessCSS.java:47)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
>       at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:59)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
>       at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:237)
>       at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:214)
>       at net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:88)
>       at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.monitoring.HudsonMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HudsonMonitoringFilter.java:114)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>       at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>       at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>       at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
>       at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>       at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:278)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$3.succeeded(SslConnection.java:148)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
>       at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.89.4.jar!/lib/layout/main-panel.jelly:36:21:  org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: Cannot get property 'escapeTestDescp' on null object
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:280)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.Namespace$ProxyImpl.invoke(Namespace.java:92)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.main_panel(Unknown Source)
>       at lib.LayoutTagLib$main_panel$1.call(Unknown Source)
>       at hudson.plugins.testng.results.MethodResult.index$_run_closure1.doCall(index.groovy:10)
>       at hudson.plugins.testng.results.MethodResult.index$_run_closure1.doCall(index.groovy)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder$1.run(JellyBuilder.java:264)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>       ... 120 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.89.4.jar!/lib/layout/main-panel.jelly:36:21:  org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: Cannot get property 'escapeTestDescp' on null object
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:726)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:281)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:276)
>       ... 139 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: Cannot get property 'escapeTestDescp' on null object
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:280)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.Namespace.invokeMethod(Namespace.java:56)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
>       at hudson.plugins.testng.results.MethodResult.index$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(index.groovy:11)
>       at hudson.plugins.testng.results.MethodResult.index$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(index.groovy)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder$1.run(JellyBuilder.java:264)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>       ... 145 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: Cannot get property 'escapeTestDescp' on null object
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:726)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:281)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:276)
>       ... 164 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'escapeTestDescp' on null object
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:60)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:47)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
>       at hudson.plugins.testng.results.MethodResult.reportDetail$_run_closure1$_closure4.doCall(reportDetail.groovy:30)
>       at hudson.plugins.testng.results.MethodResult.reportDetail$_run_closure1$_closure4.doCall(reportDetail.groovy)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:296)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.methodMissing(JellyBuilder.java:173)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31961.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:939)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovyClosureScript.invokeMethod(GroovyClosureScript.java:87)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:430)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:369)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
>       at hudson.plugins.testng.results.MethodResult.reportDetail$_run_closure1.doCall(reportDetail.groovy:26)
>       at hudson.plugins.testng.results.MethodResult.reportDetail$_run_closure1.doCall(reportDetail.groovy)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:296)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.methodMissing(JellyBuilder.java:173)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31961.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:939)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovyClosureScript.invokeMethod(GroovyClosureScript.java:87)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:75)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
>       at hudson.plugins.testng.results.MethodResult.reportDetail.run(reportDetail.groovy:14)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:74)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:62)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:147)
>       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
>       ... 165 more
>   Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:280)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.Namespace$ProxyImpl.invoke(Namespace.java:92)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.layout(Unknown Source)
>       at lib.LayoutTagLib$layout$0.call(Unknown Source)
>       at hudson.plugins.testng.results.MethodResult.index.run(index.groovy:8)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:74)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:62)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:112)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet.handleIndexRequest(JellyFacet.java:140)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.IndexViewDispatcher.dispatch(IndexViewDispatcher.java:30)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
>       at com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugin.assetbundler.filters.LessCSS.doFilter(LessCSS.java:47)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
>       at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:59)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
>       at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:237)
>       at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:214)
>       at net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:88)
>       at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.monitoring.HudsonMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HudsonMonitoringFilter.java:114)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>       at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>       at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>       at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
>       at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>       at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:278)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$3.succeeded(SslConnection.java:148)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
>       at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: Cannot get property
>   'escapeTestDescp' on null object

At some reason `escapeTestDescp` is `null` and that why the system fails while trying to get this `property`

It can be also a `Jenkins` bug. [Here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) you can post your issue or search for similar issues.

Comment: Can you tell me from where can I set this property?

Comment: If I right understand, you cannot handle with this issue. I have added information in my answer, please have a look

Comment: Thanks  Andrei Suvorkov. I will check in jenkin bug list how they are fixing it.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, you can accept it by clicking on the green check button right below the downvote button.

Comment: The issue fixed with downgrading Testng plugin in Jenkin. This is the open bug from jenkin for future reference: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26971

Comment: So it was a bug in the new version?

Comment: yes. Between someone put my question "On Hold" status so I am not able to perform much action over question.